# Не могу преобразовать json в python

Tags: python, json, парсер, requests

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://investfunds.ru/funds/5629/'
date_from = '12.11.2020'
date_to = '26.03.2021'
payload = {
    'action': 'chartData',
    'data_key': 'close',
    'date_from': date_from,
    'date_to': date_to,
    'ids[]': 5629,
    'currencyId': 1
}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
data = json.loads(r.content)['data']
print(data)
```

Почему получаю ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что там получается список (из одного элемента), а уже внутри него - словарь, а в списке можно индексироваться только целочисленными индексами. И ещё можно не преобразовывать "вручную" `content` в `json`, для этого есть специальный готовый метод в ответе на запрос. Итого данные можно взять так:

```
data = r.json()[0]['data']
```

В `data` получится:

```
[[1605128400000, 875.11],
 [1605214800000, 883.45],
 [1605474000000, 901.51],
...
```